# I am trying to make the pictures change after the user has clicked 10 or 11 times. It worked on Netbeans but not when exported into a Jar File

Tags: java, image, user-interface, onclick, jbutton

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author yolk3
 */
public class clcikerUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form clcikerUI
     */
    public clcikerUI() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        textArea1 = new java.awt.TextArea();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("David Clicker"));

        jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/newpackage/david (2).JPG"))); // NOI18N

        jButton1.setText("Click");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Click Count");

        jTextField1.setEditable(false);
        jTextField1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 48)); // NOI18N
        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Exit");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField2.setEditable(false);
        jTextField2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jTextField2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 36)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel4.setText("David Clicker 2016");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField1)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 194, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                .addGap(51, 51, 51)
                                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 530, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addGap(63, 63, 63)
                        .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 233, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(12, 12, 12))
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 93, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(401, 401, 401)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 239, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addGap(48, 48, 48)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(83, 83, 83)
                        .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 218, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap())
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(88, 88, 88)
                                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 67, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(8, 8, 8)
                                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 651, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 85, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(0, 221, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        clickNum++;
        jTextField1.setText(Integer.toString(clickNum));
        Random rand = new Random();
        jTextField2.setText(array[rand.nextInt(array.length-1)]);
        count++;
        if(count>10&&count<20){
        jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/newpackage1/david2 (2).JPG")));
        }
        else if(count>20&&count<30){
            jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/newpackage2/WIN_20160205_10_17_02_Pro - Copy.JPG")));
        }
        else if(count>30){
            jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/newpackage/david (2).JPG")));
            count=0;
        }

    }                                        
    private int count = 0;
    private int clickNum; 
    private String []array = {"David Approves","MLG David", "Easy Sevens", "Notice Me Senpai", "Please Mark, No", "Ib 45", "Eazy 7s", /*8*/"Help Me, David, Help Me!!!", "Deez Coding Skeels", "Daniel is Terrible at League", "CSGO",/*12*/ "Subscribe to Big Little Tuna", "Subsribe to Dat Fish", "Please David, Notice me", "Master Juang!!!" }; 

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        System.exit(0);
    }                                        

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    }                                           

    private void jTextField2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    }                                           
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(clcikerUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(clcikerUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(clcikerUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(clcikerUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new clcikerUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private java.awt.TextArea textArea1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: and what does it do now? does the image not change? not when it should? does the application not run?

Comment: yea the image does not change when it is in a Jar @Stultuske